# If statement from excel scores to change text in word with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have different scores in an excel sheet directly extracted from a database that have certain values. I want to extract these scores from excel and be able to change texts in a word document with if statements (e.g. if score in cell (2, 2) > 60 (in excel) = delete/replace a certain text (in word)) with VBA. Does anyone know how I would compile this macro?

The code I tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application

Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Testdoc.xlsx")

If score.Cells(2, 2) >= 60 Then

Function FnOpeneWordDoc()

   Dim objWord

   Dim objDoc

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Desktop\TestDoc.docm")

   objWord.Visible = True

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "text here"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

End Function

End If

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Function
```

Edit: New code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application

Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\UsersDesktop\Testdoc.xlsx")

If exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then Run [BLA]

If Not exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then Run [BLA2]

End If

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub

Function BLA()
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = "Old text"
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
    Wrap:=wdFindContinue

End With

End Function

Function BLA2()
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = "Old text"
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.Text = "Old text"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
    Wrap:=wdFindContinue

End With

End Function
```

Comment: Show us some of your code! What have you tried?

Comment: What is the best way to learn [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901783/1490783)?

Comment: I hope this makes it a little more clear...I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: please explain what is not working, what and where? any errors (number and description)?

Comment: I get an "expected end sub" statement after the "if" statement.

Comment: remove the following lines: `Function....` and `end function`, make some test and come back with new info... You can't add `Function` inside `Sub`.

Comment: Also, running the code line by line using "F8" or other debug options (like breakpoints) should help you understand what is going on and exactly where it is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand, since your code does not make sense. First, you have a function defined inside a sub. That will never compile. You need to separate the functions or subs.

Then you seem to end the sub with `End Function` - will also cause an error. By the way, functions return values, use Subs if you don't want to return something.

Finally, you haven't mentioned how and where you will run the code. `FnOpeneWordDoc` opens a Word docm by first opening Word, `CommandButton8_Click` opens an Excel xlsx by first opening Excel. Either you run it from Excel, then you only need to open Word since Excel is already open, or the other way around. Try the following from Excel. I don't know what you are trying to do in Word, so I commented out the code that does not compile. I hope it will set you off running in the right direction.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    Dim exWb As Workbook

    Set exWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Testdoc.xlsx")

    If exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then
        Call FnOpeneWordDoc
    End If

    exWb.Close

    Set exWb = Nothing
End Sub


Sub FnOpeneWordDoc()
    Dim objWord

    Dim objDoc

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Desktop\TestDoc.docm")

    objWord.Visible = True


    'Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    'Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    'With Selection.Find
    '    .Text = "text here"
    '    .Replacement.Text = ""
    '    .Forward = True
    '    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    '    .Format = False
    '    .MatchCase = False
    '    .MatchWholeWord = False
    '    .MatchWildcards = False
    '    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    '    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    'End With

    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Answer to comment
 - sure, that's what the `If exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then` line does. If the value in B2 is equal to or greater than 60, then run `FnOpeneWordDoc`.

Bonus tip: you can evaluate the conditions by using the immediate window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) in the VBA environment by typing a question mark `?` and then the condition:

```
?exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60
```

will return `True` or `False`.

**EDIT #2**:
You have two If-statements where one be better. Also, the second If statement is not correct. You either have `If True Then [Command]` or have the [Command] on the line below with an `End If` after - you mix the two.

Try the following basic code, then add the details later - remove everything else if possible).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    '***** Check to see if something
    '***** is bigger than something else
    If 61 >= 60 Then
        '***** Run sub FnOpeneWordDoc
        Call FnOpeneWordDoc
    Else
        '***** Do nothing
    End If
End Sub


Sub FnOpeneWordDoc()
    '***** Do something cool
End Sub
```

**EDIT #3**:
Your If statements actually work if you use the correct syntax:

```
'***** Use either one line without "End If"...
If exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then Run [BLA]

'***** ...or this syntax, where you must use "End If"
If Not exWb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value >= 60 Then
    Run [BLA2]
    '***** You can add more lines here if you want
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I understand your confusion, I'm sorry about that. I realize that functions inside a sub do not work, I tried to show what I want to do (which obviously failed). I run the code from Word VBA, so you are right, I don't have to open the document anymore..sorry for the mistake. I will try it again.

Comment: Okay, I feel like a complete moron now. Is it possible to run a conditioned function? What I mean: If value > 60 then run funtion X, if not don't run function X.

Comment: I tried to do it in multiple ways, but without getting an error the "if" still does not what I want it to do. I can't seem to condition which function VBA performs. Am I missing something? (See edit question for the new code)

Comment: Try the very simple code sample I've added and try to get it to run. You have two If statements in your new code when If Else would be better.

Comment: @user3219697 Your If statements work if you use either of the two methods in my third edit of the post.